# Intel® Core™ i5-8269U Processor has memory of LPDDR3-2133

Tags: laptop, processor, pc, memory, memory-card

I'm building a laptop. Don't ask why I just am. Im looking for memory chips for my Intel® Core™ i5-8269U Processor. I am so confused. I don't know what lpddr3 chips to get for 16gb of ram. Im leaning towards micron or sk Hynix. Most laptop companies use (SKhynix H9CCNNNBJTAL) memory for these cpus. But it doesn't exist. What memory chips out there support a rate of 2133. None. So what should I do.Can you show me the chips I need.

Comment: You need to add some kind of budget. [The Intel ARK link](https://ark.intel.com/products/137980/Intel-Core-i5-8269U-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz) for this CPU actually states that it supports DDR4-2400 as well. So you would be much better off looking for some DDR4 as its faster, and newer, and easier to buy.